# How do you declare a comment using the Razor view engine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewengine

Using ASP.NET MVC's default view engine, you can declare a server-side comment like this:

```
<%-- This is a comment --%>
```

This comment will only be visible on the server side and is not sent to the client. How would I do the same with the Razor view engine?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Start the comment block with `@*`, end the comment block with `*@`.

Similar to C# (`/*` and `*/`)

```
@* single line comment *@
```

or

```
@*
    this is a comment
    this is another
*@
```

More on Razor comments on [the Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/12/asp-net-mvc-3-server-side-comments-with-razor.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's strange though how none of my searching turned up that post on Scott Gu's blog.

Comment: With this we can not do single line comments inside a block comment.