# commenting c# and html code together in razor mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have mixed c# and html code in razor.
how can I comment the whole as a one comment, this is the code?

```
@if (Request.Cookies["area"] != null && Request.Cookies["area"].Value != "")
{
    <div>

        <div class="search-main">
            <div><input type="text" class="search-control" placeholder="Search ads..." /></div>
            <div class="search-control .search-control-border" style="cursor:pointer;overflow-y:visible;">
                <a style="display:block; width:100%;height:100%" onclick="expandCategoryDropdown()">     <span class="category-dropdown-text" style="float: left;margin-top: 2%;margin-left: 0.2em;">@(Request.Cookies["city"] != null ? Request.Cookies["city"].Value.ToString() : "Select Location")</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon category-dropdown-icon" style="float: right;margin-top: 3%;"></i></a>
                <div class="searh-dropdown" style="z-index:1">
                    <div class="inner-dropdown">
                        <ul style="margin-left:-38px">
                            @*<li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'parent')">@ViewBag.area</a></li>*@

                            @{

                                List<ListHell.CODE.Locations> lst = (List<ListHell.CODE.Locations>)ViewBag.cities;

                            }
                            <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none">
                                @ViewBag.areaStr
                                <ul style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                    @foreach (ListHell.CODE.Locations l in lst)
                                    {
                                        <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="margin-left:10px;color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'child')">@l.city</a></li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-control .search-control-border"></div>
        </div>




        <div><input type="button" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="Search" style="margin-top: -2.5% !important;margin-left: 76%;;width:20%" /></div>
    </div>
}
```

I dont want embed comment within comment. Just one commenting should do. Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, it's working in my client.

```
@{/* 


@if (Request.Cookies["area"] != null && Request.Cookies["area"].Value != "")
{
<div>

    <div class="search-main">
        <div><input type="text" class="search-control" placeholder="Search ads..." /></div>
        <div class="search-control .search-control-border" style="cursor:pointer;overflow-y:visible;">
            <a style="display:block; width:100%;height:100%" onclick="expandCategoryDropdown()">     <span class="category-dropdown-text" style="float: left;margin-top: 2%;margin-left: 0.2em;">@(Request.Cookies["city"] != null ? Request.Cookies["city"].Value.ToString() : "Select Location")</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon category-dropdown-icon" style="float: right;margin-top: 3%;"></i></a>
            <div class="searh-dropdown" style="z-index:1">
                <div class="inner-dropdown">
                    <ul style="margin-left:-38px">
                        @*<li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'parent')">@ViewBag.area</a></li>*@

                        @{

                            List<ListHell.CODE.Locations> lst = (List<ListHell.CODE.Locations>)ViewBag.cities;

                        }
                        <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none">
                            @ViewBag.areaStr
                            <ul style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                @foreach (ListHell.CODE.Locations l in lst)
                                {
                                    <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="margin-left:10px;color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'child')">@l.city</a></li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-control .search-control-border"></div>
    </div>


*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be  `@* {code} * @` for multiline.
alt. `/*` and `*/`

You can also try `ctrl + k + c` if you are using Visual Studio

Example:

```
@*
    @{
        /* C# comment */
        // Another C# comment
    }
    <!-- HTML comment -->
*@
```

[Similar Post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467496/how-do-you-declare-a-comment-using-the-razor-view-engine)

Comment: I tried not working. cant even make compiler happy runtime is long shot

Comment: its not one comment, you need to embed comment for html

Comment: remove this line @*<li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'parent')">@ViewBag.area</a></li>*@
as it will break the full block comment or use the html comment <!-- --> for this line instead of @* *@

Comment: Tried:
<%-- --%>
<% %>
@/*   */@

Comment: keep editing not working. I take it as  no to the answer. NOT POSSIBLE

Answer (score 0):

that should work

```
@* @if (Request.Cookies["area"] != null && Request.Cookies["area"].Value != "")
{
<div>
    <div class="search-main">
        <div><input type="text" class="search-control" placeholder="Search ads..." /></div>
        <div class="search-control .search-control-border" style="cursor:pointer;overflow-y:visible;">
            <a style="display:block; width:100%;height:100%" onclick="expandCategoryDropdown()">     <span class="category-dropdown-text" style="float: left;margin-top: 2%;margin-left: 0.2em;">@(Request.Cookies["city"] != null ? Request.Cookies["city"].Value.ToString() : "Select Location")</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon category-dropdown-icon" style="float: right;margin-top: 3%;"></i></a>
            <div class="searh-dropdown" style="z-index:1">
                <div class="inner-dropdown">
                    <ul style="margin-left:-38px">
                        <!-- <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'parent')">@ViewBag.area</a></li> -->
                        @{
                            List<ListHell.CODE.Locations> lst = (List<ListHell.CODE.Locations>)ViewBag.cities;
                        }
                        <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none">
                            @ViewBag.areaStr
                            <ul style="margin-left:-40px;">
                                @foreach (ListHell.CODE.Locations l in lst)
                                {
                                    <li class="select-cat-li" style="list-style-type:none"><a class="select-cat" style="margin-left:10px;color:black" onclick="select_cat(this,'child')">@l.city</a></li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-control .search-control-border"></div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="button" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="Search" style="margin-top: -2.5% !important;margin-left: 76%;;width:20%" /></div>
</div>
} *@
```

Comment: did you even see what changed on line 11

Comment: this should be accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

For Visual Studio, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

For JetBrains, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

[image: Select]

[image: Edit]

[image: Advanced]

[image: Comment Selection]

Comment: I tried not working

Comment: Go to Edit>Advanced>comment selection (If you are using Visual Studio)Selection and use the combination that is displayed there.

Comment: I'm sorry, that it is not working for you, but the solution does work.

Comment: @arlanschouwstra it can't work since he has nested comments

Comment: in that case, adding `/*your code here */` should work aswell