# How to write a comment in a Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, comments

How to write a comment in a MVC view, that won't be transmitted to the final HTML (i.e.,to browser, to response). One can make a comment with:

```
<!--<a href="/">My comment</a> -->
```

but, it is visible in the page source code in browser.

Is it possible to leave comments in '.cshtml' files only for internal use?

Comment: [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Comment: Found a duplicate of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382903/razor-comment-syntax

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467496/how-do-you-declare-a-comment-using-the-razor-view-engine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor comment syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382903/razor-comment-syntax)

Answer (score 354, accepted):

*Note that in general, IDE's like Visual Studio will markup a comment in the context of the current language, by selecting the text you wish to turn into a comment, and then using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut, or if you are using Resharper / Intelli-J style shortcuts, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.*

*Server side Comments:*

**Razor .cshtml**

[Like so:](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-server-side-comments-with-razor)

```
@* Comment goes here *@
```

**.aspx**
For those looking for the older `.aspx` view (and Asp.Net WebForms) [server side comment syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<%-- Comment goes here --%>
```

*Client Side Comments*

**HTML Comment**

```
<!-- Comment goes here -->
```

**Javascript Comment**

```
// One line Comment goes Here
/* Multiline comment
   goes here */
```

As OP mentions, although not displayed on the browser, client side comments will *still be generated* for the page / script file on the server and downloaded by the page over HTTP, which unless removed (e.g. minification), will *waste I/O*, and, since the comment can be viewed by the user by viewing the page source or intercepting the traffic with the browser's Dev Tools or a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark, can also *pose a security risk*, hence the preference to use server side comments on server generated code (like MVC views or .aspx pages).

Comment: Forgot to try it))))) I usually use Ctrl+E,C and Ctrl+E,U. Thanks a lot

Comment: This response is incorrect.  See the other response to this question.

Comment: @ZackaryGeers I'm not following - sobering's answer seems to have duplicated my original answer, and I've subsequently augmented to respond to the OP's concerns about keeping comments hidden for internal use. What is incorrect?

Comment: But I use the C# comment syntax (`//...`, `/*...*/`) in the Razor page. Shouldn't it actually be rendered as text?

Comment: It depends where you place the // comment. Razor can have C# sections (denoted by a starting @), Html and even JS sections Script sections. C# comments won't be echoed by the server. Comments in js and html will be sent to the browser.. //  comments in Html will be regarded as text and will likely be visible to the end user.

Comment: Ok but what if I WANT to display a certain comment in the page source, for example a copyright notice?

Answer (score 31):

This comment syntax should work for you:

```
@* enter comments here *@
```