# How to write a comment in a Blazor razor page/component?

Tags: blazor

I know we can comment the blazor pages/components as

```
   @*  

    comments 

    comments

    long comments
   *@
```

But is there a single line comment like what we have in c# //

Comment: You are not coding in a `cs` file but you are coding in a `cshtml` or `razor` file and you should use `razor syntax `which is what you mentioned yourself.  see  this : [Comments in Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#comments)

Comment: `@* single line *@`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is a possibility. I know pretty sad. Here is a link that explains all the different types of commenting in a razor file

[How to write a comment in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171576/how-to-write-a-comment-in-a-razor-view)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).