# What does the @* mean in a CSHTML file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I keep seeing *@ everywhere in a Visual Studio MVC Web app within all the CSHTML files, within the script tags.

Search engines refuse to let me search those characters which is ridiculous and I have struggled for hours trying to figure this out.

The lines that have the *@ are the same colors as the comments, does that mean it's commented out?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in MVC @(at) using for binding with Model . For example :

```
@model yourModel;

@foreach(var  item in Model){
  @item.yourItemFromYourModel;
}
```

So double at like this @* *@  using for comments.
For ex:

```
@*YourComment*@
```

Hope it helps ;)
Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3383662/4640991

Answer (score 4):

Jup you are correct using the `@*  *@` block you can set some content like `HTML` or `Server code` in your razor code as a comment.

Documentation: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Server-Side Comments with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-server-side-comments-with-razor)

Answer (score 0):

In fact in Visual Studio, if you just select a block of code and choose "Comment block" button in the toolbar, it will automatically put the @* and *@
So it is for comments in cshtml file